# how to redirect from unclean url to clean url using htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

i am having url like

```
mydomain.com/?q=ayx
```

i want to redirect it to straight

```
mydomain.com/ayx
```

currently using Backdrop cms , enable the clean url feature, tried to do with url redirect but didn't succeed.
I have tried the htaccess file changes as shown below, but this also not worked.
Please tell me what i doing wrong?

checked the mod_rewrite that is also enabled.

Thanks

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?q=ayz [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ayz?   [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?q=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```